# Expected identifier or '{' and Expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, xcode4.6

I am trying to move our system from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4.6 and I get following compilation errors (Same line)

```
Expected identifier or '{' 
Expected unqualified-id
```

The code causing an error is (The line - namespace PVM):

```
namespace wvNS
{
   namespace PVM
   {
       int a = 1;
   }
}
```

We have this code in number of files inside our system.
Can someone spot a light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to show the ACTUAL code that causes the problem...

Comment: I explained, the error is on the line "namespace PVM". The code INSIDE is irrelevant. I can put int a = 1 there.

Comment: Then my guess is that PVM is a macro or some other name used somewhere else.

Comment: I checked projects very thoroughly. Besides, I think in that case it would not compile on older Xcode as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt!

I found this in 10.8 SDK (Obviously was not in 10.6 SDK)

```
#define PSWP    0
#define PVM     4
#define PINOD   8
#define PRIBIO  16
#define PVFS    20
```